# ComboBox - DropDownList won't Drop Down

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drop-down-menu, combobox

Here is my code:

```
public LayoutScheduler(){
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Load += (sender, args) =>
                     {
                         this.LoadLayouts();
                     };
}

public void LoadLayouts()
{
    ImmutableSet<string> layoutNames = _store.Current.Keys;

    layoutComboBox.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (string name in layoutNames)
    {
        layoutComboBox.Items.Add(name);
    }
    layoutComboBox.EndUpdate();

    layoutComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

I have this ComboBox set up in my designer to be a DropDownList style, however, in debug I can see the ComboBox Items list grow, when it displays, it'll display the first item as it's default, however I can't drop down the list.

If I then change the DropDownStyle to a simple, editable DropDown, and do the same I get the same behaviour, UNTIL I select the text in the drop down, at which point I am able to drop down the list.

I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on here. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's the code for how this user control gets called and added to the form and displayed:

```
 var layoutSchedulerControl =  new LayoutScheduler(connected.Connection.Store, connected.Connection.Schedules);
 Form layoutSchedulerForm = Statics.CreateForm("Layout Scheduler", layoutSchedulerControl);
 layoutSchedulerForm.ShowDialog(this);
 layoutSchedulerForm.Dispose();
```

Comment: Are you sure you didnt set any other property, which will some how disable the drop down behaviour?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you change `this.Load` to `this.Shown`?

Comment: @SwDevMan81 The list is contained in a user control, and is then placed onto a form. As such, I don't believe it has a "Shown" event, but I tried with the "VisibleChanged" event, and checked if Visible was being set to true, but still no luck.

Comment: Basically, the UserControl which holds this dropdown is created, then added to a form which is then shown with a ShowDialog statement.

Comment: @MitjaBonca I've posted everything related to the drop down box, and after searching I don't believe there's anyway to outright disable a ComboBox in that way, other than to set Enabled to false.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".